# How do I call a Django function without button click

Tags: python, django

How do I call a Django function without button click.. I want to pass a variable value from views.py & i need to use in template language without forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example..

in your views :

```
def PageView(request):
    return render(request, 'yourhtml.html', {'variable_name': 'Value Of Variable'})
```

and in your html page:

```
<p> {{ variable_name }} </p>
```

and it will return `<p> Value Of Variable </p>`